# PySide6 access automatic generated items

Tags: python, frontend, pyside6

I am automatically generating some checkboxes and need to later access the value of this items. The number of items and their names are random.

self.feature is just for explanation. I dont know the values inside this list.

```
self.features =  ["feature a", "feature b", "feature c"]
for index, feature in enumerate(self.features):
    label = QLabel(self)
    label.setText(feature)
    y = index * 30 + 70
    label.setGeometry(10, y, 100, 20)
    checkbox= QCheckBox(self)
    checkbox.setGeometry(90, y, 100, 20)
```

The best case would be, if I could assign the checkboxes a value depending on the current 'feature' variable. And later access the element via this 'feature' value.

Comment: Just create a list as an instance attribute (ie. `self.checkboxes = []`) and then append them, or if there are no duplicate "features" use a dictionary. Also, why are you using a label and an empty checkbox? And you should also use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), not fixed geometries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful answer.
I am not really an expert yet, but layout management helps a lot. Make things more beautiful and user friendly